# How upgrade from ggts 3.6.0 to ggts 3.6.1

Tags: grails, ggts

my project has been generated under ggts 3.6.0, which uses grails 2.4.2 respectively.
Now that ggts 3.6.1 is released I want to proceed with 3.6.1 using grails 2.4.3.
But using of 3.6.1 is only possible, if I add grails 2.4.2 to the grails preference page, so that ggts is working with grails 2.4.2, though 2.4.3 is available on the preferences page. As I understand so far 2.4.3 will only be used for new projects.

Is there a chance to use 2.4.3 for the existing project ?

peter strotmann
Dortmund, Germany

Comment: solved the problem by creating a new project with grails 2.4.3 and copying all artifacts (domains, controllers, views etc.) from 2.4.2 Version. It took me 2 hours and some trial & error for fotgotton artifacts (config entries etc.). It is not the smartest solution but finally it works.... You don't have to be intelligent and smart as long as you know how to help yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It was unnecessary. You could have solved as follows: Just change the **application.properties** file (in the project) to **app.grails.version=2.4.3**, then right click on the project -> Grails Tools -> Refreshing Dependencies or Ctrl + Alt + Shift + G > clean and finally Refreshing Dependencies.